# how to publish iphone Binary (.app) file on your Hard Drive?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development and want to know that how to publish the iphone binary (.app) file on your hard drive rather than App Store.

Because I have heard that one have to publish it on App Store and than from there he can install it into iphone device.

Because the application on which I am working is not supposed to be public as its for our company's employees so no need to publish on App Store if its not much necessary or forced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your company should create a enterprise developer account and get all the needed certificates for their server. This way you can deploy the app from your companies server without using the App Store.

Comment: is there any solution to not creating any account with apple?

Comment: Azhar, you are going to have to pay Apple for one of the two developer accounts. What is wrong with an Apple account?

Comment: @jrtc27: Actually I do not have any concerns with Apple Account but to get payment for account from company I must have strong argument and proofs to get them convince.

Comment: @Azhar: Is "you can install the app on all devices in the company" a good enough argument? There is really no easier way and I doubt that you want to jailbreak 300+ devices.

Comment: @Azhar Proof: Pay or you can't use the app.

Comment: They are convinced to get enterprise developer account now :)

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at [Ad Hoc Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2)? You can install the app in max 100 devices (if i remember well). When you create your Ad Hoc profile in the itunes developer portal you have to add the `UDID`s for each device will be installed the application, then the just drag the `.app` in itunes and synchronize.

Comment: Actually application is supposed to be installed in more than 300 devices. so is your solution still valid?

Comment: nope, @JustSid has given you the answer for more than 100 device. I think the only solution to distribute an app without an Apple certificate is to run the application in jailbroken devices.